# Synchronizing threads: Achieving a order

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, posix, semaphore

I have 3 threads . All are of equal priority. Each has to print "I am thread i" where i corresponds to the thread number. How do I synchronize them in such a way the output should be 
I am thread 1
I am thread 2
I am thread 3

This would be simple to accomplish if the priorities of each thread are different, but if I want to keep the same priority how can I accomplish this?

Are there any operating system primitives or any POSIX mechanisms which I can use to achieve this?

Comment: First introduce threads and then serialize their execution - what would be the purpose of that? Anyway, depending on your platform you'll have several sync primitives at your disposal that you can use for this. E.g. you could have a manual reset event per thread that is initially unsignaled and that each thread blocks on until it is signaled. Then signal the first one to wake up thread 1. Then have it signal event 2 when done to wake up thread 2, and so on.

Comment: 'This would be simple to accomplish if the priorities of each thread are different' - no, it would not.

Answer (score 1):

I presume executing the threads in a specific order as you want is more from a academic/learning perspective, else it is defeating the purpose of multi-threaded programming.

One of the ways to achieve it is using condition variables as provided by pthread library.

`pthread_cond_wait()`  will cause a calling thread to block on some variable value and once it reaches a certain value, this blocked thread can be 'woken up' using `pthread_cond_signal()`

See [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) for a simple example on description and code about showing to use pthread condition variables.